# Вывод массива объектов в консоль в таком же виде, как и document.getElementsBy***Name

Tags: javascript

При выполнении `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body'))` в консоль выводится массив с названиями элементов: `[body]`.

Можно ли сделать так же с кастомными объектами? Для примера возьмем следующий массив объектов `a = [{name: 'one'},{name: 'two'},{name: 'three'}]`. Результат `console.log(a)` будет `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`, а я хотел бы получить что то вроде `[one, two, three]`

*p.s. Если кто то знает как правильно задать заголовок этого вопроса - поправьте меня плз=)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам себе, может кому-нибудь пригодится. Если создавать объекты функцией, то при логировании в консоль будет выводится название данной функции (`function.name`). Таким образом через `eval` можно для каждого объекта объявлять свою функцию-конструктор с необходимым именем.

Удобно использовать такой подход, если вы делаете для тестов выборку объектов в консоле, например я писал свой класс для поиска объектов в загруженной 3d модели, это выглядит примерно так

```
> model.find("~tabletop~ks12")
< ▼ (3) [tabletop_ks12_with_border, tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_pp_300x150, tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_monolite_ceramic_300x150]
```

В развёрнутом виде:

```
> model.find("~tabletop~ks12")
< ▼ (3) [tabletop_ks12_with_border, tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_pp_300x150, tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_monolite_ceramic_300x150]
    ▶ 0: tabletop_ks12_with_border {…}
    ▶ 1: tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_pp_300x150 {…}
    ▶ 2: tabletop_ks12_with_border_sink_monolite_ceramic_300x150 {…}
      length: 3
    ▶ __proto__: Object
```

Можно конечно использовать `.toString()` или прописать в конструкторе что то типа `.log()`, но тогда вы выведите не объект, а его текстовое представление, и не сможете через интерфейс консоли посмотреть его содержимое или сохранить в глобальную переменную для дальнейших действий с этим объектом. В целом такое сочетание информативности и функциональности определенно полезно, но в тоже время серьезное усложнение кода, возвращающего данный объект.

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужно вывести только поля `name` в массиве. Тогда нужно использовать `Array.map` или сделать свой кастомный метод массива, например:

```
Array.prototype.showNames = function() {
  return this.map(item => item.name);
}

var a = [{name: 'one'},{name: 'two'},{name: 'three'}];
console.log(a.showNames());
```

Comment: Я хотел без доп функций=) Нашел способ, если объекты создавать конструктором, то при выводе будет что то типа `[название_конструктора1, название_конструктора2, ...]`, то есть выводит `function.name`. Можно при наполнении объекта создавать необходимый конструктор под каждый и вывод будет сразу информативнее, для дебаггинга одного скрипта мне сейчас сверх удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Фильтр по ключу используй, и выводи все через цикл.

***Пример:***

```js
var filters = [{
  "name": "abc"
}, {
  "name": "xyz"
}, {
  "name": "asd"
}, {
  "name": "lol"
}];

for (i in filters) {
  console.log(i);
  for (key in filters[i]) {
    console.log(key + ": " + filters[i][key] + ", ");
  }
}
```

***Другой вывод, на любителя:***

```
filters.forEach(function(obj, index){
    console.log(index);
    for (var key in obj){
        console.log(key, obj[key]);
    }
});
```

ps. Если хочешь чтобы вывод был в одну строку, записывай все в одну строку, а затем выводи через `console.log`

Comment: Не совсем то что я имел ввиду, но за ответ всё равно спасибо)